# When someone has not changed facially and you run into them suddenly

Tags: idioms, expressions, sentence-request

How to tell someone we haven't seen for a long time (say a couple of years) that they have not aged at all and look exactly the same as they looked back then.

I have heard the following sentence:

> You haven't even aged a day.

Does it work properly here?

I am well aware there are many ways in English to indicate the same thing, but the expression in my question should indicate exactly the message within my explanations.

Please kindly let me know about it.

Answer (score 2):

*You don't look a day older* or *You haven't changed a bit!* seem the most idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 0):

*You have aged gracefully* is a polite and decent way to respond.

Comment: "Aging gracefully" is very different from "you haven't change a bit."  To age gracefully means to show the visible signs of age, but in a good way (and in particular, without trying to hide those signs with hair dye, makeup, plastic surgery, etc.).